# Mongodb not returning more than 100 records

Tags: mongodb

Below is the Mongo query I am using, but this is returning 100 as max records even if I increase the maxDistance to the maximum possible value. I know there are lot of records mongo is not returning, value more than 15 miles as a maxDistance its always returning 100 documents , please help.

```
db.business.aggregate([ 
{ "$geoNear" : { 
    "maxDistance" : 0.005046438589510322, --this is 15 miles
    "distanceMultiplier" : 3963.191 , 
    "near" : [ -84.464374 , 33.864826] , 
    "spherical" : true , 
    "distanceField" : "distance",
    query: {
                "category": { "$eq": "restaurant" } 
            }
    }
 } ,  
    { "$match" : { "status" : { "$in" : [ "active"]}}}, {
    $group: {
      _id : null, 
      count : {$sum : 1}
    }
  }
 ])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add `limit`, otherwise it uses the default which is to return the first **100** documents:

```
{ "$geoNear" : { 
    "maxDistance" : 0.005046438589510322, --this is 15 miles
    "limit" 1000,
    ...
```

The above will return 1,000 documents